# Merge Sort returns the same array I input

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I implemented a mergesort algorithm but it returns the exact same array I pass as an input. The following is the code. I am suspecting the pseudocode that our professor gave us is wrong. But I am not sure. I have tried to implement is as best as I can.

```
int len(double *a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a[count] != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

double* merge(double* b, double* c, int N) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    double* result = new double[N];
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        if ((i < len(b)) && (j >= len(c) || b[i] <= c[j])) {
            result[k] = b[i++];
        } else {
            result[k] = c[j++];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void merge_sort(double* a, int N) {
    if (N >= 2) {
        int mid = (N+1)/2;
        double *left = new double[mid];
        double *right = new double[mid];
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            left[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < mid; j++) {
            right[j] = a[mid + j];
        }
        merge_sort(left, mid);
        merge_sort(right, mid);
        a = merge(left, right, N);
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: in cases like that it would be appreciated if you provided information on what the input is, the conventions. Without leaving it all for us to guess.

Comment: The unsorted array: 0.982292 0.728327 0.206361 0.856009 0.639465

Comment: Use a debugger. You will see that the argument passed to the parameter a is not changed after the function exits. Then read some of good C++ books.

Comment: That's not what I meant. For example I deduced from your code that the array is null terminated, but at first it puzzled me why are you using double* a like a character string.

Comment: unrelated, this code is leaks memory like a sieve leaks water. If the goal is sorting the partition in-place (not to be confused with in-place merging, which is harder than it sounds) there is no reason to copy the left and right partitions in `merge_sort` and local temporary dynamic storage in `merge` should be just that; *temporary*. It should be cleaned up as well. It would be less confusing if you wanted an actual sorted copy to just (a) create the copy, then (b) in-place sort *that*.

Comment: @OP  *I am suspecting the pseudocode that our professor gave us is wrong* -- Pseudocode is not real code.  Your issue has to do with C++ language details, not pseudocode.  Going by what you posted, the pseudocode is correct, but your usage of the C++ language and parameters is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, you assign your result to the local var `a`, which is then lost. You need to return `a`, or pass the input as a reference/pointer, otherwise any changes are only to the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in the function are basically local variables, they behave like any local variable in this function, except their initial value is set by code that calls this function. `a` is a pointer that stores the address of first element of your `double` array.

As it's a local variable, you can modify it but when the function ends, it will be discarded like all other local variables of the function.

There are several ways to deal with this problem, each with their own up and downsides. The most obvious is to return final value of `a` when you're done sorting. You could also pass a pointer TO a pointer to this function, and then you would be able to modify the pointer outside the function:

```
void function(int** argument){
    *argument = another_function();
}
```

, but that severely restricts the source of your input. It no longer could be a local array passed by address like this:

```
int x = 10;
int *y = &x; // if this is what you want to change
function(&y); // this works

// now x is still 10, y points to a different place in memory which can store a different value

int x[1]; // if you would like to change this array in place though...
function(x); // this is how you would call the function, but it would fail because it can't change the address that x refers to
```

Comment: He modifies not the values, but the address stored in the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You main issue is here:

```
// You pass in a pointer to the data here.
// the parameter `a` holds a pointer to the data.
void merge_sort(double* a, int N) {
    if (N >= 2) {

        // STUFF

        // Here you write over `a` (which is fine)
        // BUT: You don't pass the value back.
        // So the caller never knows what the new value is.
        a = merge(left, right, N);
    }
}
```

To fix this. I think it is a mistake to allocate a new array in `merge()`. Rather re-use the array you have. You have already copied the data into `left` and `right` to be sorted. The merge should merge the data back into the original array `a`.

```
       // Change this:
       a = merge(left, right, N);
```

into

```
       merge(a, left, right, N);
```

Now in `merge()` you can use `a` as the destination.

```
void merge(double* result, double* b, double* c, int N)
    // No longer need to allocate space for result now.
```

---

There are a couple of other issues:

1: What do you need `len()` for?

```
int len(double *a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a[count] != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You should already know the length of all parts you should not be re-measuring it. Also this function is completely wrong (the double array is not `\0` terminated).

2: The length of `b` and `c` is not obvious.

```
double* merge(double* b, double* c, int N) {
```

You get the wrong value because you call `len()` which is not correct.

You could calculate from `N` but that has issues in that you need to make sure both you merge functions use **exactly** the same method and that is error prone in the long run. I would personally pass the size of each array as parameters to the function.

3: You leak your intermediate arrays!

You call `new` to allocate storage.

```
        double *left = new double[mid];
        double *right = new double[mid];
```

But you don't deallocate these objects so they are leaked (for every call to new there should be a corespodning call to `delete`).

---

Overall. You can solve a cople of issues by using more C++ style techniques (rather than the C style you are using). Iterators and std::vector spring to mind.

Comment: Great answer Martin. :)